# How I can implement the constructor of the class who is inline explicite?

Tags: c++

How I can implement the constructor of this class? The constructor is inline and explicit and call the draw function. I try to implement that's in the file .h and .cpp and that's generate an error.

```
#ifndef DRAW_H
#define DRAW_H
#include "item.h"
#include <set>
#include "random/random.hpp"
namespace nvs
namespace lotto
{
class Parameter;

class Draw : public Item
{
  inline std::set<unsigned> draw(const Parameter & parameter) const;
  public:
  /*!
   * this function call the private function draw()
   */
  inline explicit Draw(const Parameter & parameter);
  /*!
   * \brief constructor virtuel by default.
   */
  virtual ~Draw() override = default;
};
inline explicit Draw::Draw(const Parameter & parameter)
{
    draw(parameter);
}
inline std::set<unsigned> Draw::draw(const Parameter & parameter) const
{
    std::set<unsigned> values;
    unsigned cpt=0;
    unsigned length = parameter.length();
    while (cpt < length)
    {
        unsigned temp = random_value(parameter.maximum(), parameter.minimum());
        if ((values.find(temp))==values.end())
        {
            values.insert(temp);
            cpt++;
        }
    }
     return values;
}
}   // namespace lotto
}   // namespace nvs
#endif
#endif // DRAW_H
```

Output :

```
C:\Users\George\Documents\TD07\draw.h:86: erreur : 'explicit' outside class declaration
inline explicit Draw::Draw(const Parameter & parameter)
                                                      ^
C:\Users\Mitch\Documents\TD07\draw.h:86: erreur : no matching function for call to 'nvs::lotto::Item::Item()'
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error? Did you try removing `explicit` from the method definition, and looking if that produced a change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have the `explicit` keyword outside the declaration in the class. If you add it to the declaration, it is marked explicit and you don't need to add it to the definition. Just remove it from the definition and it should be solved. That is exactly what the error is saying.
On that note, you have the `inline` keyword on the definition and declaration. Adding it to only one of them should be enough and the other one may be remove.

Comment: Can also remove `inline` from the declaration at the same time.

Comment: ok thank you, and now I have this error  "C:\Users\Mitch\Documents\TD07\draw.h:86: erreur : no matching function for call to 'nvs::lotto::Item::Item()'
 Draw::Draw(const Parameter & parameter)
                                                                     ^"

Comment: @john good point! Added that in.

Comment: @Ayxan Except we disagree on whether it needs to be on the declaration or definition. I always have it on the definition.

Comment: @john I suppose I should add a note about you can have it either on definition or declaration.

Comment: @Ben That's because your `Item` class does not have a default constructor. Either add one, or call an `Item` constructor you do have from your `Draw` constructor.

Comment: @john thank I look this hypothesis ^^

Comment: Your right @john, the reason is because this class inherite of the class Item and in Item there are not a default constructor. So I make that's : "inline Draw::Draw(const  Parameter & parameter ) : Item(draw(parameter),parameter)
    {
    
    }"

Comment: @Ben Seems reasonable.